# Why In_Array() PHP not working for multi-dimesional Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, codeigniter-3

I am trying to see if a string is in an array but when try to search with in_array it always return false even if the string is in the array

```
  $array = { ["cardId"]=> int(233) ["mask"]=> string(14) "498765xxxx8769" ["brand"]=> string(4) "VISA" ["scheme"]=> string(4) "VISA" } }
    if(in_array('512345xxxx2346', $array)
    {
       echo "512345xxxx2346 found !!";
    }else {
      echo "512345xxxx2346 not found !!";
    }
```

**Output**

```
 512345xxxx2346 not found
```

Please help

Comment: Your example is working as expected. Well, there are syntax errors, but logically I wouldn't expect anything else

Comment: @dan08 I have updated the question

Comment: Can you write a viable example please?

Comment: @dan08 so I don't understand what you meant by viable example

Comment: That's not a usable PHP array. And you have syntax errors. There is no way that code snippet gives that output

Comment: If one ignores the syntax errors, your example does not contain a multidimensional array.

Comment: This is the correct array ( [cardId] => 233 [mask] => 498765xxxx8769 [brand] => VISA [scheme] => VISA )  the previous one is var_dump result

Comment: Making assumptions to make this workable: https://3v4l.org/lkAKW

Comment: Are you talking about associative array? Why are you keep talking about multidimensional array and not including a valid [mcve]????

Comment: Why is it tagged with both laravel and codeigniter? Especially when neither the example code nor the question text makes any reference to either one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple cards, you could iterate through them and check each one.

```
$cards = [["cardId" => 233, "mask" => "512345xxxx2346"], ["cardId" => 234, "mask" => "498765xxxx8769"]]
foreach($card in $cards) {
  if (in_array("512345xxxx2346", $card)) {
    echo "512345xxxx2346 found!";
  } else {
    echo "512345xxxx2346 not found!";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not work at all, and the result would be correct anyway because you start with a 4 in the declaration and test for one starting with 5.

Arrays in PHP are declared inside square brackets, with the key separated by `=>` from the value.

```
$array = ["cardId" => 233, "mask" => "512345xxxx2346 ", "brand" => "VISA", "scheme" => "VISA"];
if (in_array('512345xxxx2346 ', $array)) {
  echo "512345xxxx2346 found !!";
} else {
  echo "512345xxxx2346 not found !!";
}
```

Comment: @samuel What if is multi-dimensional array like this (["cardId" => 233, "mask" => "512345xxxx2346 ", "brand" => "VISA", "scheme" => "VISA"], ["cardId" => 234, "mask" => "498765xxxx8769 ", "brand" => "MASTERCARD", "scheme" => "MASTERCARD"]);

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is all wrong, you either declare arrays in square brackets **["key" => value]** or with **array("key" => value)**.

With the proper syntax, your example returns a match with the if check:

```
$array = array(
   'cardId' => 233,
   'mask' => '498765xxxx8769',
   'brand' => 'VISA',
   'scheme' => 'VISA'
);

if(in_array('498765xxxx8769', $array)) {
   echo "498765xxxx8769 found !!";
} else {
    echo "498765xxxx8769 not found !!";
}
```

Assuming you need to check multiple cards, you would probably want a multi-dimensional array, where you put arrays inside the array (separated by commas).

In that case, you should use a loop to check every array (or card) inside the first array:

```
$array2 = array(
    array(
        'cardId' => 233,
        'mask' => '498765xxxx8769',
        'brand' => 'VISA',
        'scheme' => 'VISA'
),
    array(
        'cardId' => 367,
        'mask' => '839510xxxx0045',
        'brand' => 'VISA',
        'scheme' => 'VISA'
    )
);

$i = 1;
foreach ($array2 as $a) {
    if (in_array('498765xxxx8769', $a)) {
        echo "Card " . $i . ": 498765xxxx8769 found !!" . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Card " . $i . ": 498765xxxx8769 not found !!" . "<br>";
    }
$i++;
}
```